# Boost 1.4.0, "assert" identifier not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost, assert

I'm trying to compile an old project that was originally written for linux on windows.
It uses boost 1.4.0, and whenever I compile it throws error C3961: "assert" : identifier not found.  I'm using Visual Studio 208 SP1
When I drill down into assert.hpp it includes this:

```
# include <assert.h> // .h to support old libraries w/o <cassert> - effect is the same
# define BOOST_ASSERT(expr) assert(expr)
```

BOOST_ASSERT is actually what's failing, and VS doesn't seem to recognize assert() even though assert.h is obviously included.
As far as I can tell, all the fails are in files that are part of boost, not my own code, but it throws about 1200 of them.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try with `#include <cassert>`?

Comment: ok...that fixed it, but I had to modify boost to do it... which bugs me.  Any other way I can do this?

Comment: Hi, having exactly the same problems here, and came to the same two lines of code which puzzeled me. Surprisingly, including #include <cassert> did not help in my case. I'm Using Visual Studio 2005 Professional and boost 1.4.0, code works fine on Ubuntu. I'm using CMake 2.8.1 to generate the project files, so I'm wondering if this adds to the problem (wouldn't be the first time).